# Swipe Unity 2D With the capture area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make this in Unity in 2D Mode?

[image]

How can I make this swipe, which stop on necessary to me position: first and second slide? What should I study or in what direction should I look for?

How I can make this buttons, which i imaged like arrows?

And lower forms display the current slide.

I'm not asking to solve the problem for me, but I need a help of experienced developers.

Comment: your english is way too bad, I honestly can't understand you.

Comment: I guess you are looking for a ScrollRect Component in Unity3D. Google it and you will find a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need any experienced developper for that. What you want to achieve is a swipe so I assume you aim for mobile game. 
Google's your best friend here's the first link is likely to solve your issue : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvJCjy8vIrY.

But for programming, the first requirement is english since 99% of documentation, forums, code... will be in english.

Comment: You should include the core elements of any link in your answer so that if the link goes dead, your answer remains useful.